# Is it an Install or Update?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, app-store

Is there a way to tell (like in the appDelegate) if an app has been updated from iTunes as opposed to installed?

I know I could build something that looks in NSUserDefaults or something I already have a version in the AppStore and need to know if I'm updating someone's install.

Comment: Why would you want to know that?

Comment: Does your app store any user data at all? If it does, you can check if that data exists and then store some key in user defaults that you can use to prevent checking that again.

Comment: Well, it does if you run it but ideally I would want to know even if the user has never opened the app before. I need this for our analytics department to keep track of new installs versus version updates.

Comment: You can do that via iTunes Connect sales reports, they indicate if app was updated or downloaded for first time.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the bundle version number when you lanch the app for the first time. So the first time you install the app regardless what bundle version number it is, the object was never store on disk before and thats how you detect a fresh install.

every time you release an update, you also bump your bundle version number and you can detect that in code as an update (and of course after detecting the update you bumb the version number stored as well)

Comment: Right. That makes sense from this point on. But that doesn't work for me since the app is already released.